# Using the Quandl package in Python, get the AttributeError "module 'Quandl' has no attribute get"

Tags: python, pip, quandl

On a Windows computer with Anaconda installed, I tried to install the Quandl Python package by typing the following in the command line:

```
pip install Quandl
```

I get a confirmation "Successfully installed Quandl-2.8.9". Next, I would like to use Quandl. In a new Python script in Spyder try the following commands:

```
import Quandl
mydata=Quandl.get("FRED/GDP")
```

However, this yields the error message

```
AttributeError: module 'Quandl' has no attribute 'get'
```

I suspect that Quandl is somehow not installed properly. Is there some aspect of the installation I'm missing?

Comment: Have you named the script you're working on `Quandl.py`?

Comment: Yes, I did actually. That was it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out by kindall, I had inadvertently named the script "Quandl.py". I renamed it and the code works as expected.

Comment: yep, this bit me too

Comment: This one got me too

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of subtle changes and requirements. For example import statements should look like this.

```
import pandas as pd
import quandl

df = quandl.get('WIKI/GOOGL')

print(df.head())
```

And your script should be named `Quandl.py` with a capital Q.

Answer (score 0):

As explained in your code you mentioned:

```
import Quandl
mydata=Quandl.get("FRED/GDP")
```

The correct import should be with small letter 'q'

```
import quandl
mydata=quandl.get("FRED/GDP")
```

And it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Renaming the python file name to `Quandl.py` worked for me.